# how to fix “repair device” for android TV emulator in android studio avd manager?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-tv, television

which ever emulator i download it show the error repair device. Currently I have downloaded the marshmallow version TV emulator in android studio avd manager but there is no run option as you can see in the image i have added the link. I searched on internet there is no much source for this issue. If anyone had faced this issue plz answer or add link for solution.

[image]